# PHP: Looping over an object loops over member array

Tags: php

```
foreach ($pElements as $pElement) {
  var_dump($pElement);
}
```

If I execute the above, I notice it dumps each value in the 'nodes' array even though `$pElement` is an object. Can anyone explain this behavior?

At first I thought running `foreach` on an object automatically searches for a member array, but the first listed array `namespaces` seems to be ignored.

Here is the full object `$pElements`:

```
/var/www/html/phpTestArea/index.php:35:
object(Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler)[38]
  protected 'uri' => null
  private 'defaultNamespacePrefix' => string 'default' (length=7)
  private 'namespaces' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'baseHref' => null
  private 'document' => 
    object(DOMDocument)[2]
      public 'doctype' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      public 'implementation' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      <public properties removed>
  private 'nodes' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(DOMElement)[36]
        <public properties removed>              
      1 => 
        object(DOMElement)[35]
        <public properties removed>
  private 'isHtml' => boolean true
```

Comment: What does the first sentence mean exactly? What do you expect and what is the actual output exactly?

Comment: I'm new to PHP but I thought every object member would be iterated over. The actual output is the nodes array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code of that class [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.2/src/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.php), you can see that it implements two interfaces, defined as follow:

**Countable**: this define how the instances of the class should behave when passed to the native php `count` function. The counting depends on the implementation.

```php
interface Countable {
    abstract public count(void): int
}
```

**IteratorAggregate**: this is the one that return an iterator (which extends Traversable) that defines *how* and *what* should be traversed.

```php
interface IteratorAggregate extends Traversable {
    abstract public getIterator(void): Traversable
}
```

So if you look closely into the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.2/src/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.php#L1065) for these two functions, you will see how these are implemented:

```php
/**
 * @return int
 */
public function count()
{
    return \count($this->nodes);
}

/**
 * @return \ArrayIterator|\DOMElement[]
 */
public function getIterator()
{
    return new \ArrayIterator($this->nodes);
}
```

So if you call `count($pElements)`, the object's internal count function will be executed, therefore you would get the count of the `nodes` property.

In the same way, if you iterate with a foreach over `$pElements`, you are iterating over the `nodes` property, as this is the behaviour defined by `getIterator()`.